# Google Drive SDK - changes( ) Key Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I'm checking Drive for changes using the following code:

```
    deltaDict = drive_service.changes().list(includeDeleted = True, startChangeId = driveRC.deltaCursor).execute()
    if not str(driveRC.deltaCursor) == str(deltaDict['largestChangeId']):
        print '*** Change Detected ***'
        fileItems = deltaDict['items']
        for item in fileItems:
            isDeleted = item['deleted']
            theFile = item['file']
            fileID = theFile['id']
            fileLabels = theFile['labels']
            fileName = theFile['title'] 
            isTrashed = fileLabels['trashed']
```

and this was working fine for some time. At the moment however, I'm seeing the error:

```
    theFile = item['file']
    KeyError: 'file'
```

but looking at [the documentation](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/drive_v2.changes.html#list) this looks to me like it should work? Can anyone spot what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, `item['file']` is present only if the file has not been deleted, so you can only use it if `item['deleted']` is False or at least wrap it in a try/except block.

```
for item in fileItems:
    isDeleted = item['deleted']
    try:
        theFile = item['file']
        # Rest of your code
    except KeyError:
        print "Item deleted"
```

Comment: Ah I see, missed that, changed it there and that's working fine now. Cheers for the help